# while using WebAuthn in FF why does navigator.credentials.get() return "DOMException: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform..."

Tags: firefox, webauthn, yubico

I'm trying to implement WebAuthn but while calling navigator.credentials.get() it always returns `DOMException: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.` after I press the button on the Yubikey even tho it works fine while calling navigator.credentials.create()
I'm using firefox 118.0.1 for Ubuntu

here is the content of publicKey I'm calling it with:

```
$("#loginButton").click(function() {
        const result = navigator.credentials.get({
            publicKey: {
                challenge: new Uint8Array([139, 66, 87, 64, 66, 25, 78, 
                    64, 66, 25, 87, 139, 64, 66, 25, 78]),
                rpId: "localhost",
            }],
                userVerification: "preferred",
            }
```

I expected it to return a valid promise but it returns an invalid promise and gives out an error in the console

Comment: Did you get this to work with the answer from @cody-salas? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Hi Julie, I think I am getting closer. The error seems to be linked to the fact that `allowCredentials` is either not present or the `id` contained in it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `PublicKeyCredentialRequestOptions` isn't formatted correctly. Try this snippet instead:

```
navigator.credentials.get({
  publicKey: {
    challenge: new Uint8Array([
      139, 66, 87, 64, 66, 25, 78, 64, 66, 25, 87, 139, 64, 66, 25, 78,
    ]),
    rpId: "localhost",
    userVerification: "preferred",
  },
})
```

Also try going into your Firefox configurations (about:config) and check the following settings are enabled

- `security.webauthn.webauthn` is true
- `security.webauthn.webauthn_enable_usbtoken` is true
- `security.webauthn.ctap2` is true

Comment: I run into the exact same issue. My `PublicKeyCredentialRequestOptions` are formatted correctly and everything seems to be working fine. Registration in the same browser on the same site works. Do you have any hint as to what I should look for?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I did some further testing, and still the only way I can recreate the error is by setting `security.webauthn.webauthn_enable_usbtoken` to false. So ensure that you go into your FF settings (about:config), and set the config to true (along with the other settings mentioned above). Weirdly enough when this setting is false it allows for registration, but not auth.

Comment: @CodySalas @mvreijn I tested it in Chrome and it gave me the more helpful feedback in a popup that my authenticator isn't registered with this website (which I think means my key doesn't accept something in the publicKey) so I'm pretty sure I just copied the challenge wrong or something
- also I checked my about:config and the only thing it showed when I searched for the settings you mentioned were `security.webauthn.webauthn_enable_android_fido2.residentkey` and `security.webauthn.ctap2`

Comment: I have double-checked the settings and `security.webauthn.webauthn` did not exist. However creating it as a boolean makes no difference. My error message is the same as Julie's but the error name is `NotAllowedException`. And my FF is 119.0.1 running on Mac. Can it be that the challenge encoding we are using is wrong?